# populate json data into html template based on fields

Tags: javascript, c#, html, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement to populate HTML with JSON data returned from a web API call.
The HTML is also a template file which will be exposed to the customer.
Wherein the customer can edit some of the fields in the HTML.

---

For example to remove some headers and columns etc. Assuming the HTML has table data format.
Whenever a user clicks on a button on the client side, a web API call is performed, a JSON data is what we get.
Now this JSON data has to be loaded onto the HTML template based on the tags it has.

---

We have to use c# to populate the HTML.
All the rendering(population of HTML) must happen on the server side.
We may use javascript also but right now the server solution is in asp.net web-API. The main requirement is the rendering must happen on the server side using any language. 
How to do it in C#?

**HTML**

```
<h3>Table Name</h3>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Row Names</th>
    <th>NewItems</th>
    <th>ChangedItems</th> 
    <th>Errors</th>
    <th>total</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Types</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Properties</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Lists</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Entries</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "Compare Report": {
        "Types": {
            "NewItems": 0,
            "ChangedItems": 0,
            "Errors": 0,
            "Total": 0
        },
        "Properties": {
            "NewItems": 0,
            "ChangedItems": 0,
            "Errors": 0,
            "Total": 0
        },
        "Lists": {
            "NewItems": 0,
            "ChangedItems": 0,
            "Errors": 0,
            "Total": 0
        },
        "Entries": {
            "NewItems": 0,
            "ChangedItems": 0,
            "Errors": 0,
            "Total": 0
        }
    }
}
```

sample table

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between the JSON and the HTML?  That is, are NewItems/ChangedItems/Errors/Total represented by rows or columns in the table?

Comment: Sorry, should have correlated them. edited it now.
 NewItems/ChangedItems/Errors/Total  are column names
types/props/lists/entries are row names

Comment: Are the columns (currently shown as Col1/2/3/4 supposed to represent NewItems/ChangedItems/Errors/Total)?  Also, are you expecting a table of zeros (given your current JSON data)?

Comment: Are you making an AJAX call to retrieve the JSON?  If so, are you using jQuery?

Comment: @jhenderson : yes col1,2,3,4 - newitems,changeditems,errors, total.
yes a table of zeros also is expected.

Comment: Can you share the model that you are using within your view?

Comment: Not ajax actually... From client side we would make a webapi call using axios. Now at the server side as soon as we get jSON data we have to populate that into html template which is also at server side. Once fully populated we would return a link to that html file on the client.

Comment: There isn't any model. It would be enough if we can just populate html with JSON at server side and return the link of that loaded html on the client.

Comment: Given that you are using ASP.NET with Web API, why wouldn't you use a model as part of the MVC framework?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Model (as part of ASP MVC), and a JSON Serializer/Deserialize to convert the JSON into an object (since you are not using AJAX/jQuery).  A JSON Deserializer is available as part of:

- The .Net [JavaScriptSerializer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) (depending on which version of .Net you are using), or
- The Newtonsoft [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library

You can use the JSON Deserializer to map the JSON to an ASP MVC Model and then render that within your view.

If you examine [this .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hUImNv), you will see your examine in conjunction with Newtonsoft.JSON and ASP MVC 4.5.  (There was no built-in support for the JavaScriptSerializer class.)

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, thank you. I guess the view being used is cshtml. Isn't there a way without using model. As this view has to be just html not cshtml and shouldn't contain any code.

Comment: Correct.  The view is the .cshtml. You could do this without a model if you use a [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: The Model is used as part of the MVC framework that is loaded by the controller and used by the view.  You could deserialize the JSON via Javascript, but you would still need to java Javascript to render the table.

Either way, you will need an object (C# or JavaScript) to take that JSON and the build a table dynamically.

Comment: One more thought: There are a lot of different ways to build this table.  Some better and/or easier than other ways.  I merely went with the one that I thought made the most sense for you, given the SO tags that you used and the info that you provided in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Yes, we can use viewbag. While using viewbags or model , the view has to be cshtml right ? . Correct me if I'm wrong.  But my requirement is that view has to remain just html. As at a later point html will be deployed and made available to user to change the template. If you have ideas in this area please suggest it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the view _is_the cshtml.  I think that there may be confusion around the view not being "just HTML" on your part.  The example that I created, shows the view (.cshtml), and that view uses the (Razor syntax)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor], which when processed by the server sends an HTTP response that is HTML-only to the client (browser).  

If you can only use HTML, and are not making and AJAX call, the JSON isn't static, and you aren't using JavaScript, then it isn't clear how you will manipulate either: a) the view (with HTML), or b) the DOM

Comment: That is, if the JSON is obtained by making a call to the server. You must either integrate it into HTML via MVC or load it via something that manipulates the DOM (like jQuery or JavaScript).